sound effect after each rotation
I want to produce sound effect after each rotation of wheel play?
i tried insert import AVF Foundation but it only play after press button.
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var scrollAmount = 0.0
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: QuakeView()) {    
                   ZStack {
                    Image("Q")
                        .resizable(capInsets: EdgeInsets())
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: 206.0, height: 206.0)
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.horizontal)             .rotationEffect(.degrees(scrollAmount * -51.43))
                    
                    ZStack {
                        Image("IMG")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)           .frame(width: 250.0, height: 250.0)
                        
                    }
                    .frame(width: 100.0)
                    .accessibilityIdentifier("Identifier")        }
                .offset(x: 0)
                .focusable(true)
                .digitalCrownRotation($scrollAmount, from: 0, through: 14, by: 1, sensitivity: .low, isContinuous: false, isHapticFeedbackEnabled: true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

